# Joining large data in spark streaming

Tags: sql, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

We have a big customer table with 7 million records and we are trying to process some transaction data (500K messages per batch) coming from the kafka stream.

During the processing, we need to join the transaction data with customer data. This is currently taking us around 10s and the requirement is to bring it down to 5s. Since the customer table is too large, we cannot use broadcast join. Is there any other optimization that we can make?

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Aggregate [(count(1),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false) AS count#119L]
+- Join Inner, Some((custId#110 = rowkey#0))
   :- Subquery custProfile
   :  +- Project [rowkey#0,no_mkt_opto_flag#5,thrd_party_ads_opto_flag#4]
   :     +- Filter ((no_mkt_opto_flag#5 = N) && (thrd_party_ads_opto_flag#4 = N))
   :        +- Subquery jz_view_sub_cust_profile
   :           +- Project [rowkey#0,thrd_party_ads_opto_flag#4,no_mkt_opto_flag#5]
   :              +- MetastoreRelation db_localhost, ext_sub_cust_profile, None
   +- LogicalRDD [key#109,custId#110,mktOptOutFlag#117,thirdPartyOptOutFlag#118], MapPartitionsRDD[190] at rddToDataFrameHolder at custStream.scala:166

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
count: bigint
Aggregate [(count(1),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false) AS count#119L]
+- Join Inner, Some((custId#110 = rowkey#0))
   :- Subquery custProfile
   :  +- Project [rowkey#0,no_mkt_opto_flag#5,thrd_party_ads_opto_flag#4]
   :     +- Filter ((no_mkt_opto_flag#5 = N) && (thrd_party_ads_opto_flag#4 = N))
   :        +- Subquery jz_view_sub_cust_profile
   :           +- Project [rowkey#0,thrd_party_ads_opto_flag#4,no_mkt_opto_flag#5]
   :              +- MetastoreRelation db_localhost, ext_sub_cust_profile, None
   +- LogicalRDD [key#109,custId#110,mktOptOutFlag#117,thirdPartyOptOutFlag#118], MapPartitionsRDD[190] at rddToDataFrameHolder at custStream.scala:166

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Aggregate [(count(1),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false) AS count#119L]
+- Project
   +- Join Inner, Some((custId#110 = rowkey#0))
      :- Project [rowkey#0]
      :  +- Filter ((no_mkt_opto_flag#5 = N) && (thrd_party_ads_opto_flag#4 = N))
      :     +- MetastoreRelation db_localhost, ext_sub_cust_profile, None
      +- Project [custId#110]
         +- LogicalRDD [key#109,custId#110,mktOptOutFlag#117,thirdPartyOptOutFlag#118], MapPartitionsRDD[190] at rddToDataFrameHolder at custStream.scala:166

== Physical Plan ==
TungstenAggregate(key=[], functions=[(count(1),mode=Final,isDistinct=false)], output=[count#119L])
+- TungstenExchange SinglePartition, None
   +- TungstenAggregate(key=[], functions=[(count(1),mode=Partial,isDistinct=false)], output=[count#122L])
      +- Project
         +- SortMergeJoin [rowkey#0], [custId#110]
            :- Sort [rowkey#0 ASC], false, 0
            :  +- TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(rowkey#0,200), None
            :     +- Project [rowkey#0]
            :        +- Filter ((no_mkt_opto_flag#5 = N) && (thrd_party_ads_opto_flag#4 = N))
            :           +- HiveTableScan [rowkey#0,no_mkt_opto_flag#5,thrd_party_ads_opto_flag#4], MetastoreRelation db_localhost, ext_sub_cust_profile, None
            +- Sort [custId#110 ASC], false, 0
               +- TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(custId#110,200), None
                  +- Project [custId#110]
                     +- Scan ExistingRDD[key#109,custId#110,mktOptOutFlag#117,thirdPartyOptOutFlag#118]
```

Comment: I posted a question on this and got it closed. The 10 secs is nice to know in fact. Imagine a 100M customers in China. cache used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assuming customer data is constant across mini-batches, partition this customer data on customerId using hash partitioner and cache it in RDD/DF.
2. Since transaction data is coming from Kafka, this data can also be partitioned on same key using hash partitioner while publishing into Kafka
   https://www.javaworld.com/article/3066873/big-data/big-data-messaging-with-kafka-part-2.html

This should reduce time in joining two dataset but only condition is partition key should be same in both datasets(transaction data and customer data).